# Ruby: void value expression while using if else with break

Tags: ruby, github, pull-request

I am new to Ruby language. I am working on integrating the [Danger](https://github.com/danger/danger) to add checks on GitHub PR. One of the use case is to check if modified files in my PR contains particular change. I have added below code in DangerFile

```
filesArray = ["Resources/Config.plist", "Resources/Deployment.plist"]

def modified_files_contains_change(files, change)
    does_contain_required_changes = false
    for file in files do
        message "diff in #{file}"
        diff = git.diff_for_file(file)
        patch_contains_change = diff.patch =~ #{change}
        if diff && patch_contains_change
            does_contain_required_changes = true
        else
            does_contain_required_changes = false
            break
        end
    end
    message "Does contain changes in all files => #{does_contain_required_changes}"
    does_contain_required_changes
end

if modified_files_contains_change(files, change)
   warn "Some useful warning message goes here"
end
```

While running this on my CI, I am getting below error

```
[!] Invalid `Dangerfile` file: void value expression. 

 #  from Dangerfile:33
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #              does_contain_required_changes = false
 >              break
 #          end
 #      end
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

I tried searching but didn't understand the what's going wrong. Can someone please help me understand what is the exact issue? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `=~ #{change}` is read as `=~` because `#` starts an inline comment. You probably wanted `=~ change` there instead.

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin If I removed # then it gives me below error
```[!] Invalid Dangerfile file: type mismatch: String given. ```

Comment: You should start using a better editor. Even the extremely simplistic, naive, stupid syntax highlighting of [so] already clearly shows your problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=~ #{change}` is read as just `=~` because `#` starts an inline comment. `=~` expects a regular expression on one of sides. To fix the issue, change the line below:

```
patch_contains_change = diff.patch =~ #{change}
```

to:

```
patch_contains_change = diff.patch =~ Regexp.new(change)
```

This assumes you are passing a string as `change`.

---

Also, this would be *more or less* rubyish way to accomplish the task:

```
def modified_files_contains_change(files, change)
  does_contain_required_changes =
    files.all? do |file|
      message "diff in #{file}"
      # break will immediately exit the `all?` unless diff is present
      break false unless diff = git.diff_for_file(file) 
      diff.patch =~ Regexp.new(change)
    end

  message "Does contain changes in all files => #{does_contain_required_changes}"
  does_contain_required_changes
end
```

---

To return a file where we found an issue:

```
def modified_files_contains_change(files, change)
  problematic_file =
    files.detect do |file|
      message "diff in #{file}"
      (diff = git.diff_for_file(file)).nil? || diff.patch !~ Regexp.new(change)
    end

  does_contain_required_changes = problematic_file.nil?
  if does_contain_required_changes
    message "All good!"
  else
    message "We have issues with file #{problematic_file}"
  end
  does_contain_required_changes
end
```

Comment: Thank you @Aleksei Matiushkin for your help. Using `Regexp.new(change)` worked perfectly :)

Comment: If one the file has not changed in my PR then `git.diff_for_file(file).patch =~ Regexp.new(change)` throws error as `[!] Invalid Dangerfile file: undefined method patch for nil:NilClass.` Can we make it optional by checking if diff has the file then only call the patch method? Otherwise I need to switch my function instead of using rubyish way

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Does break will update the value of `does_contain_required_changes` to `false` in this case?

Comment: Sure. `break false` does immediately exit the iteration returning `false`.

Comment: It worked perfectly now. Just wondering whether we can return the `file` along with `false` so that I can use it `warn` message? Does ruby supports tuples?

Comment: Ruby does support tuples, but if you need a file name it’d be easier to return a problematic file name back and assume `nil` means “all good.” See the update.

Comment: Does `problematic_file` contain single file if `change` is not present in single file or multiple files when `change` is not present in multiple files? This will help us give meaningful warning message so that developer can make `change` in all files in one go? Also can I return `problematic_file` along with `does_contain_required_changes` on last line because this is reusable function?

Comment: To get all the files use select instead of detect and check if the outcome is empty instead of checking whether it is nil.

Comment: It worked by using `select` & checking against `empty`. Thank you very much for your help :)